# Display absolute links to downloaded files via youtube-dl?

Tags: php, youtube

I've set up youtube-dl on my shared Debian 3 host so I can access it via an URL to pass address to what I want to download so it would download it on my host.

I was wondering if there is a way to display URL links to file(s) downloaded by last request on a web page for easier download.

So for example, if you call domain.com/youtubedl.php?url=www.youtube.com/watch?v=000000 would download it and then display this on the page:

http://domain/download_directory/youtubefile.mp4

so you can easily download it by clicking on that link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, the video will be saved in the current operating directory of the script which has called youtube-dl. The default filename is `videoname-videoid.extension`. For example, I downloaded [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TF00hJI78Y) with the name "PHP Programming" and the video ID of "7TF00hJI78Y". When it was downloaded, it was in the directory of my batch file which I used to call youtube-dl, and was called "PHP Programming-7TF00hJI78Y.mkv". The extension can be defined as per the following [information from youtube-dl's Git-Hub page](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection). I would suggest not leaving the files in this directory, however, keeping youtube-dl outside of the public website directory, and moving the video files through your script to a public directory for downloads.